# Adding react app to an existing wordpress website

Tags: javascript, htaccess

I have built a react app and I want to add it to my existing wordpress website. So basically when you visit mydomain.com/reactapp you should see the app.
But for now I am getting a white page and in my console there is: 
https://www.mydomain.co.uk/static/css/main.cc05123b.css 404 (Not Found)

Do i have to change something in my htaccess?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to include scripts and styles properly as it has been done here https://github.com/radekzz/wordpress-react-in-theme

```
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_react_app' ); 
function enqueue_my_react_app(){ 
    foreach( glob( get_template_directory(). '/myReactApp/build/static/js/*.js' ) as $file ) {      
// $file contains the name and extension of the file        
$filename = substr($file, strrpos($file, '/') + 1);         wp_enqueue_script( $filename, get_template_directory_uri().'/myReactApp/build/static/js/'.$filename); 
}   foreach( glob( get_template_directory(). '/myReactApp/build/static/css/*.css' ) as $file ) {        
// $file contains the name and extension of the file        
$filename = substr($file, strrpos($file, '/') + 1);         wp_enqueue_style( $filename, get_template_directory_uri().'/myReactApp/build/static/css/'.$filename);   
}
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

I just needed to change the publicPath inside my webpack.